# Prevent URL manipulations including /proc and /etc with fail2ban

Tags: apache

I get many attacks on my debian apache server that include URL-manipulations like

```
http://url_on_my_eserver/?username=/etc/passwd
```

How can I block these attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fail2Ban should never be your first line of defense, after [properly handling the input](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) you can utilize Fail2Ban by using a `failregex` like this

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*GET.*\/etc\/passwd
```

Another commonly used filter to [block the PHP File Injection/Inclusion attacks](http://blogs.buanzo.com.ar/2009/04/fail2ban-filter-for-php-injection-attacks.html)

```
[php-url-fopen]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = php-url-fopen
logpath = [YOUR_ACCESS_LOG_PATH]
maxretry = 1
```

You can include that in your `jail.conf`

**Update:**
As a response to your comment, you can use multiple lines in `logpath`, for example:

```
logpath = /somepath/*wild/log
          /some/other/path/log
```

Comment: thanks, I added this to my `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/php-url-fopen.conf`: `failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\?.*\=\/(etc|proc)\/.* HTTP\/.*$`

Comment: I use `logpath = /var/kunden/logs/*access.log` but how can I add another path too? I also have logs in `/var/log/apache2/*access.log`

Comment: @rubo77, I've updated the answer for you

Comment: could it be, that too many logfiles in the apachelog will slow the server down, if you use fail2ban filters? (at my server over 250 differing logfiles, one for each customer)